# LINQ entity query performance

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have a silly question. I would like to know if there is performance difference between these two queries:

```
var cObject = from cust in entities.Customer 
              where cust.id == cid
              select cust;
```

and

```
var cObject = entities.Customer.First( c=> c.id == cid);
```

My query return only one record as I am querying with the primary key. But do they make any difference?

Comment: Your first line of code doesn't execute any SQL. The second does. So yes, there will be a difference.

Comment: @Craig: Doesn't the DataContext have to execute *some* sort of SQL to retrieve the record?

Comment: It does, in the event you enumerate the results. But the first line doesn't do that.

Comment: @Craig: I presume you are referring to lazy loading.  If you are, your first comment is opaque, to say the least.

Comment: No, I'm not talking about (EF) lazy loading. I'm talking about the fact that the first line of code has no call to `.First()` (...or `.ToList()`, or...), so the two statements are not equivalent.

Comment: It's not "lazy loading" he's talking about, it's "delayed execution"

Comment: @tster: Yes, that's what I meant.  I guess they're two different things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Performance wise, they should be similar.

Type wise they are different though. The first returns an <strike>IEnumerable</strike> IQueryable object with a single element. The second actually returns a Customer object.

Comment: The first line returns an `IQueryable`, strictly speaking. But this is generally correct if one presumes that eventually someone will actually look into the queryable.

Answer (score 1):

If your LINQ provider supports the notion of a "single record query", then a query using `First` would probably be slightly faster.

Note that you could use the first one and then do `cObject.First()` to get the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

As Craig Stuntz points out in the comments on the question, you have to be careful about profiling Linq code, since <s>lazy loading</s> delayed execution can skew your profiling results.

To get a clear reading, you would have to call `ToList()` to force the query to fully execute, and then you would have to do the same on your second example to make it apples to apples.

In any case, were the second query rewritten to return an <s>IEnumerable</s> IQueryable with one customer object instead of a single customer object, the two statements would be functionally identical.

Answer (score 0):

There is no performance.

First Microsoft introduce

```
var cObject = entities.Customer.First( c=> c.id == cid);
```

Edit: Returns `IQueryable`

Then they added sugar to it , to make work easy is

```
var cObject = from cust in entities.Customer 
          where cust.id == cid
      select cust;
```

Edit Returns `customer object`

Comment: That's what I thought too, but see Justin's answer posted here

Comment: i was knowing that,When i was planed to edit power has gone .. So..

Any way thanks